# How do I insert json output inside an input value and a select list

Tags: jquery, json

I currently have a script that that display the city and state once a valid zipcode is provided. Currently I can get the json output to print as text but when I try to insert as an input value and a select value I get nothing. Here is the code that I am using

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4 offset4">
                <div class="well">
                     <h4>Info from ZIP Code</h4>

                    <label>Enter a Zip Code</label>
                    <input id="PostalCode" type="text" placeholder="A legit ZIP Code.">
                    <p><span class="label label-info">City</span>  <span id="ContactCity"></span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="optionfield" id="fieldContactCity">
                        <label class="optionLabel" for="ContactCity">Contact City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="" value="" name="ContactCity" id="ContactCity">
                    </div>
                    <p><span class="label label-info">State</span>  <span id="State"></span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="optionfield" id="fieldState">
                        <label class="optionLabel" for="State">Contact State</label>
                        <div class="ap_block_clearing" id="sState">
                            <select name="State" id="State">
                                <option value="">- Select -</option>
                                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="California">California</option>
                                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                                <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                                <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                                <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                                <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                                <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                                <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                                <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                                <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
var jQ9 = $.noConflict(true);
jQ9(document).ready(function () {
    jQ9("#PostalCode").keyup(function () {
        var ZIPCode = jQ9('#PostalCode').val();
        jQ9.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + ZIPCode + '&sensor=false',
            success: function (jsonData) {
                // Do stuff after the JSON arrives.
                console.log('Success!');

                //Let's make some variables to keep our code clean.
                var city = jsonData.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
                var county = jsonData.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
                var state = jsonData.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;

                // Setting the target spans to the values we want to show.
                jQ9('#ContactCity').text(city.toString());
                jQ9('#State').text(state.toString());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: first and formost... **ID should all be unique**..you have two elements with the same id _ContactCity_

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the AJAX requests to the `keyup` of the postal code input. I will assume initially the text box is empty. On the first key up, the ZIPCode variable in the keyup handler will get the value in the box. Say you typed '6'. In that case, you will be making an AJAX request to the following URL - note the '6' for the address query string parameter:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6&sensor=false

Manually executing that request, you can clearly see that the `address_components` property of the JSON object does NOT contain an element at `address_components[3]`.  You just need to tweak your code to handle that. You could also check if the zip code input value has a length of 5 (for a 5-number zip code) and only execute the AJAX code in that case, but I would still check that the array contains an element at that index to be sure.

```
var ZIPCode = jQ9('#PostalCode').val();
if(ZIPCode.length == 5){
    //Ajax request
```